# IIS getting "value does not fall within the expected range" exception

Tags: iis-8

I am unable to change the authentication mode to custom on any App pool even the default ones.I am getting ["value does not fall within the expected range"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gf5U.png) exception

Comment: You will have to describe further what you have done and at which step this error message occurs. IIS configuration is governed by strict rules, so if you feed wrong data, such error message is expected.

Comment: I have been using the same details on another machine and it works fine whereas when I am trying to set up my new machine on win 10 and after creating the website in IIS I am unable to set custom identity. Go to IIS > Select any app pool say .netv4.5 (default one)> go to advanced settings change identity to custom > press ok> enter ok on setting page

Comment: I am also facing similar issue with default app pools given in IIS

Answer (score 4):

I've had this exactly error message on IIS when trying to start a website and the problem was that the binding was wrong, there was a "space" after the url.

Check your bindings for any wrong characters and if there's anything else wrong with it.